# Get a dynamix URL from Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I'm new to JS and I have googled a lot to find this without real results. So I will turn to the community to hopefully help me.

I made a script that will give me a URL. I want this URL clickable. I think its simple, but I don't see it yet

```
`var keuzeAdvies = document.getElementById('keuze-advies'),
keuzeKenmerken = document.getElementById('keuze-kenmerken'),
keuzeVullingen = document.getElementById('keuze-vullingen'),
resultBtn = document.getElementById('btn-result'),
resultaatLink = document.getElementById('resultaat-link');

resultBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

    var advies = keuzeAdvies.value,
        kenmerk = keuzeKenmerken.value,
        vulling = keuzeVullingen.value,
        resultaat = document.getElementById('resultaat');

    if (kenmerk === '') {
        kenmerk = kenmerk;
    } else {
        kenmerk = '+' + kenmerk;
    }


    if (vulling === '') {
        vulling = vulling;
    } else {
        vulling = '+' + vulling;
    }


    function res() {
        var r = advies.value + kenmerk.value + vulling.value;
        return(r);
    }


resultaat.innerHTML =  "https://timalux.com/collections/dekbedden/" + advies + kenmerk + vulling;`
```

So the bottom result does give me a useable URL, not clickable. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need an anchor tag, do this at the end

```
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.href = "https://timalux.com/collections/dekbedden/" + advies + kenmerk + vulling;

    link.innerText = 'Link'


    resultaat.append(link)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it just gives me the part in the beginning, the variables value is not passed into the string.

Comment: Please add a working example of what you are doing, maybe I can help you out with that

Comment: Hi Palash, You can find it on http://www.studiowassink.nl/java/timalux/keuzewijzer.html. I translated the part that is important to understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only problem left is that IE and Edge do not accept the 'append' function.